# Render partial in a view helper (ZF3)

Tags: php, zend-framework3

How could I utilize existing partials from within a ViewHelper class?

```
<?php

namespace Navigation;

use Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper;

class MenuViewHelper extends AbstractHelper
{

    public function render($container = null)
    {
        // need something like $this->partial() here
        return $this->getPartial("navigation/topmenu"); // ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getView` method of `AbstractHelper` (aka. `HelperInterface`) then call `partial` method. Here's an example:

```
class MenuViewHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->getView()->partial('navigation/topmenu');
    }
}
```